# Finding Patterns in Lists of Strings and Identifying Groups

Tags: c#, regex, string, c#-4.0, pattern-matching

I am looking for ways to identify groups without knowing the exact strings. The strings may differ from list to list but the repetition of the pattern is obvious by looking at it. I have never used REGEX expressions but just not starting to use them, I feel this is harder than it may seem.

Zone1

Zone1ModuleA

Zone1ModuleB

Zone1ModuleAWheel1

Zone1ModuleAWheel2

Zone1ModuleBWheel1

Zone1ModuleBWheel2

Zone2

Zone2ModuleA

Zone2ModuleB

Zone2ModuleAWheel1

Zone2ModuleAWheel2

Zone2ModuleBWheel1

Zone2ModuleBWheel2

The list will contain a much larger list of these patterns. These names may change in the future so i want to be able to recognize the pattern. The end result would match all the **Zone**, **ModuleA**, **ModuleB**, **ModuleAWheel1**...so on. I am digging through REGEX tutorials and would appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i do not know, if this is what you want to achive, you could try this:

```
void Main()
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"[A-Z][^A-Z]*[AB]?");
    var lines = linesInFile
        .Replace("\\r", "")
        .Split(new[] { '\n' })
        .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i));

    var listOfTokens = new List<string>();

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(line))
        {
            var value = match.Value;
            if (!listOfTokens.Contains(value))
            {
                listOfTokens.Add(value);
            }
        }
    }

    listOfTokens.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

private string linesInFile = @"Zone1
Zone1ModuleA
Zone1ModuleB
Zone1ModuleAWheel1
Zone1ModuleAWheel2
Zone1ModuleBWheel1
Zone1ModuleBWheel2
Zone2
Zone2ModuleA
Zone2ModuleB
Zone2ModuleAWheel1
Zone2ModuleAWheel2
Zone2ModuleBWheel1
Zone2ModuleBWheel2";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i found other ways around looking through the names but still used a very similar solution on another section of the project.